# How can I change language dynamically?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mobile, multilingual

I'm a newbie with jquery mobile, php and javascript.

I want my users to be able to click a button (javascript on click event) that will execute a "setlocale()" php command. This will allow the current page to be dynamically re-displayed in a different language (French).

I understand that javascript is client side and php is server side and cannot communicate variable values directly.

So, is linking to the current page with  $_POST['language'] a possible way way to do this or is there another method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mainly when your client-side page is displayed the server-side .php script has already ran and is finished. Setting anything for PHP does not make the page change itself. You woulhd have to employ some sort of AJAX content loading and forward a language variable to the .php serving the AJAX. Rather use $_GET in this case. What you do with it in your .php would need further investigation in your code...

Comment: I would like to use $_GET and return to the same jqm internal page after the user clicks on the select language button. However my testing suggests that it is not possible to use $_GET on jqm internal pages.

Comment: $_GET works great if no internal pages in jQuery mobile. What a shame :-(

Answer (score 0):

Use XMLHTTPRequest to submit data to a PHP file and get the responses. There are plenty of tutorials on the internet about it, for example on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: I wish people would stop linking to W3Schools, it's an awful resource.